# How to access to 2D array of char* through structure?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct, implicit-conversion

Here is a 2D array of char*, storing for example different strings in different languages :

```
typedef enum
{
    FRENCH,
    ENGLISH,
    GERMAN,
    LANGUAGES_COUNT
} languages_t;

typedef enum
{
    HELLO,
    THANK_YOU,
    WORDS_COUNT
} words_t;


char *text_tab[WORDS_COUNT][LANGUAGES_COUNT] =
{
    {"bonjour", "hello", "guten tag"},
    {"merci", "thank you", "danke"}
};
```

No trouble to access it :

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", text_tab[HELLO][ENGLISH]);
    printf("%s\n", text_tab[THANK_YOU][FRENCH]);
    printf("%s\n", text_tab[HELLO][GERMAN]);
   return 0;
}
```

Now, I don't want to access text_tab directly, but through a structure :

```
typedef struct
{
  int a;
  char ***txt; // here is not working
} test_t;

test_t mystruct = {5, text_tab};
```

The idea is to access text_tab this way :

```
printf("%s\n", mystruct.txt[BONJOUR][ANGLAIS]);
printf("%s\n", mystruct.txt[MERCI][FRANCAIS]);
printf("%s\n", mystruct.txt[BONJOUR][ALLEMAND]);
```

How to declare the field "txt" in the structure ?
I only use static allocation and I don't want to copy the content of "text_tab" in "txt", juste use a pointer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array

```
char *text_tab[WORDS_COUNT][LANGUAGES_COUNT] =
{
    {"bonjour", "hello", "guten tag"},
    {"merci", "thank you", "danke"}
};
```

has the type `char * [WORDS_COUNT][LANGUAGES_COUNT]`.

So a pointer to elements of the array has the type `char * ( * )[LANGUAGES_COUNT]`

Hence the structure can be declared like

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t a;
  char * ( *txt )[LANGUAGES_COUNT];
} test_t;
```

And in main you can declare an object of the structure type like

```
test_t mystruct = { sizeof( text_tab ) / sizeof( *text_tab ), text_tab };
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORDS_COUNT     2
#define LANGUAGES_COUNT 3

typedef struct
{
    size_t a;
    char * ( *txt )[LANGUAGES_COUNT];
} test_t;

int main(void) 
{
    char *text_tab[WORDS_COUNT][LANGUAGES_COUNT] =
    {
        {"bonjour", "hello", "guten tag"},
        {"merci", "thank you", "danke"}
    };
    
    test_t mystruct = { sizeof( text_tab ) / sizeof( *text_tab ), text_tab };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < mystruct.a; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < sizeof( *mystruct.txt ) / sizeof( **mystruct.txt ); j++ )
        {
            printf( "%s ", mystruct.txt[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
bonjour hello guten tag 
merci thank you danke
```